# Suddenly, high-value characters in text file display as octal

Tags: character-encoding

Using emacs 28.2 (build 2) on MacOS 12.6.5 on 16” M1 2021.

About six months ago, I updated emacs. Now all my old files have their higher-value characters spelled-out in octal format. For example:

What I see:  **I meet with Pena\234\364\362\371s sub, Georgette, at 1400.**

What I should see: **I meet with Pena’s sub, Georgette, at 1400.**

Yes, they are valid octal characters (i.e., when I do `C-x =` they show as themselves). The coding system info on the mode-line is `-UUU:-`.

I’ve tried visiting the file using various coding systems via `C-x <RET> r` before opening the file in Dired. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `UUU:` in the modeline indicates that Emacs opened the buffer expecting to find UTF-8 encoded text with Unix–style line endings. UTF-8 is generally the best choice for text today, so this is good.

If `\234\364\362\371` is actually what you see, then the file is not actually in UTF-8. Specifically, the first byte (`\234`) looks like a continuation byte, but it should only come after a byte that starts a multi–byte character. It clearly doesn’t, which is an error.

Similarly, the other three bytes each look like the start of a multi–byte character, but none of them are followed by continuation characters. Thus all four bytes are considered to be errors and Emacs displays them accordingly.

I don’t recognize the coding system the file is in, but if you want to guess then you could use `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` to reopen the file with a different encoding.